# How to implement an animated style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to implement animated style properties for components in a way that I can import the animated style to a global stylesheet, and then use it as needed, as opposed to bogging down component files with numerous animations. is there a way to do this?

functional animation:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Animated } from "react-native";

export const basic = () => {

  const [value] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(value, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 10000,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }),
      Animated.spring(value, {
        toValue: 100,
        useNativeDriver: true,
        speed: 12,
        bounciness: 8
      })
    ]).start();
  });

  const opacity = value.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0.0, 1.0]
  });

  const rotation = value.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 50, 100],
    outputRange: ["0deg", "90deg", "180deg"]
  });

  return { opacity, rotation };
};
```

in global stylesheet:

```
import basic from '../../etc' *or 'import {basic} from "../etc" ' ?*

const {opacity, rotation} = basic;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  animation_target: {
    opacity: opacity,
    transform: [{rotateX: rotation}]
  }
});
```

inside any component that wants to use animation:

```
<View style={styles.cell}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.touchable}
    onPress={() => onSelection()}
  >
    <Animated.Text
      style={styles.animation_target}
    >
      {props.contents}
    </Animated.Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Not sure about the setup of the animation at all, let alone implementing in a functional 'stateless' manner

Id like to see some opacity/rotation action, but nothing in the way of opacity/rotation is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`Const` is the keyword for declaring constants.

`Const` is not reallocatable for literal value.

Furthermore, the `const` keyword should be assigned a literal value at the same time as the declaration.

And the way to declare it seems wrong.

Usage

```js
const { value } = this.state.value;
```

Therefore, set the animation value through the status value.

```js
 state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),  // Initial value for opacity: 0
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
      this.state.fadeAnim,            // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: 1,                   // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 10000,              // Make it take a while
      }
    ).start();                        // Starts the animation
  }
```

And if you want to assign a style to a variable, you need to write down the value at which the status must change. If you write like a questioner, the computer will find a value named value.

```js
  const opacity = this.state.fadeAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0.0, 1.0]
  });
```

There seems to be a mixture of things. For more information, please refer to the [official document](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations) and try to follow it slowly

Comment: Im trying to do this, as I asked in my question, in terms of a stateless functional component. here's the closest example I can find for what im attempting: https://codeburst.io/butter-smooth-animations-in-react-native-93a3b86adf1
since this implementation uses const the same ways I have, how can I get my animation working with a similar implementation?

Comment: The example you are saying is 'conf' but it is saving the function and not the value you want to change itself. Here, we only use the value that we're going to change. It's not like you're doing it.

Comment: what can I change in my code to achieve this animation without using a stateful component?

Comment: You can use props to receive status values to the `const` variable.

Comment: what would that look like? 
`const basic = (props) => { 
    const [value] = useState(new animatedValue(props));` ?

Comment: It depends on what's in the props.

Comment: `const basic = (props) => { const { value } = useState(new animatedValue(props.value));`

Comment: Please refer https://codeburst.io/props-and-state-in-react-native-explained-in-simple-english-8ea73b1d224e

Comment: I’m confused because there are no props for this component

Comment: To do what you want, you need to be able to understand props. Look up the data and understand it.

Comment: It seems you're mis-understanding. I understand what props are. what im saying is this isn't a "component" in the technical sense. there are no props. it is not implemented as a component. i.e: `< basic someProp={someValue} />`

Comment: unless you're suggesting I import `basic` and implement it in the component I want through the implementing-component's props? as opposed to implementing the `basic` component in the style sheet and then trying to use the style?

Comment: Are you saying you want to set up your own components and get a style-only value?

Comment: ultimately I wanted to keep the animation functions separate from the components they're used in, and have some kind of AnimationDelivery class, that would choose different animation functions based on a range of buttons pressed

Comment: It looks like you need a redux to do what you want.